# How to make this nested loop continue in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Here is my code:

```
#!perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = (
    1 => "a",
    2 => "b",
);

foreach my $num ( keys %hash ) {
    while (<DATA>) {
        s/$num/$hash{$num}/g;
        print;
    }
}
__DATA__
121212
11111
222
```

I intend to replace all numbers with the corresponding values that exists in hash. But it outputs:

```
a2a2a2
aaaaa
222
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Why is the foreach loop run once only? Who can explain it for me? And how should I change the code? I want it to output:

```
ababab
aaaaa
bbb
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The reason the `foreach` loop appears to run only once is because you're reading from `<DATA>` one line at a time.  The second time you loop through the outer loop, there's no more data left to read from data in your inner loop.  Instead why don't you read all the `<DATA>` into a list first:

`@mylist = <DATA>`

And then loop over this list in your inner loop.

Comment: I see. it works now:   `my @text=<DATA>;
foreach my $num ( keys %hash ) {
 foreach (@text) {
        s/$num/$hash{$num}/ge;
 }
}
print @text;`

Comment: In both cases, you are going to loop (`k` *x* `n`) times where `k` is the number of lines and `n` is the number of patterns. His outer loop is more expensive in terms of IO, yours is more expensive in terms of memory footprint. Although combining keys in one pattern makes the `s///` more expensive than the plain `s///` you're using, I think looping only `k` times without increasing the memory footprint is better.

Comment: I meant, of course, had the OP written `while (<DATA> ) { for ... }` of had rewound `DATA` after each `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the file for each key in the hash, or slurping the file, you can combine the keys of the hash into one search pattern.

Note that in the current version of your script as well as in [@Benj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460235/100754), the order in which the substitutions are applied is *indeterminate* in that the ordering of keys returned by [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) can differ across `perl`s or even across different runs using the same `perl`.

Which means you should pick an ordering, and stick with it unless you like surprises. The following script combines both ideas. I decided to put longer keys before shorter ones which makes sense in most contexts.

```
#!perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = qw(1 a 11 zz 2 b);

my $pat = join '|', 
          map qr/\Q$_\E/, 
          sort { length $b <=> length $a }
          keys %hash
          ;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/($pat)/$hash{$1}/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
121212
11111
222
```

Output:

```
ababab
zzzza
bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is what Benj points out, that the `DATA` file handle is at eof for the second iteration of `foreach`. But also that you print the values during the first iteration.

If you are going to replace only one character for another, i.e. the length of your key/values are never longer than 1, I think you should use [`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    tr/12/ab/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
121212
11111
222
```

The transliteration operator will replace all the characters in the string in one go. The one problem is that the `tr///` operator must be hard coded, so no dynamic switching of characters.

If you want to use a hash, you should take Sinan's caution to heart if your key/values can be longer than 1. For example, if you have both keys `1` and `11`, which should take precedence over the other? However, if it is single character replacements, this is a way to do it smoothly:

```
my %hash = qw(1 a 2 b);

while (<DATA>) {
    s|(.)| $hash{$1} // $1 |ge;
    print;
}
```

Note the use of the regex modifier `/e`, it makes the substitution evaluate the RHS and insert the return value. In this case, we make use of the [`//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or) operator. What it does is check if the hash value is defined, and if not, just use the key instead. Similar to

```
if (defined $hash{$1}) {
    $hash{$1};
} else {
    $1;
}
```

Or

```
defined $hash{$1} ? $hash{$1} : $1
```

Note also that since it takes one character at the time with `(.)`, it will only work for single character keys.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is simply to do the `foreach` inside the `while`, as

```
#!perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = (
    1 => "a",
    2 => "b",
);

while (<DATA>) {
    foreach my $num ( keys %hash ) {
        s/$num/$hash{$num}/g;
    }
    print;
}
__DATA__
121212
11111
222
```

As others have pointed out, the problem with the original program was the read position of the `DATA` filehandle. The `rewind` function is normally used to reset the position of a filehandle back to the beginning so it can be read again, but in the specific case of `DATA` it doesn't work properly, because of the way that the handle is really just perl's internal filehandle on the `.pl` file itself. However, you can save the position using `tell` and then reset back there for each iteration using `seek`:

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

my %hash = (
    1 => "a",
    2 => "b",
);

my $pos = tell DATA;

foreach my $num ( keys %hash ) {
    seek DATA, $pos, SEEK_SET;
    while (<DATA>) {
        s/$num/$hash{$num}/g;
        print;
    }
}
__DATA__
121212
11111
222
```

Gives the output:

```
a2a2a2
aaaaa
222 
1b1b1b
11111
bbb
```